# SVG2PNG - src path is copied into my destination path

Tags: svg, gruntjs

Hello I am using grunt to copy all my SVG's and then convert them into pngs which will be then placed in a different folder but whats happening is that I am getting the exact same folder path from my src path INSIDE my destination path.

```
  svg2png: {
        all: {
            files: [
                // rasterize all SVG files in "img" and its subdirectories to "img/png"
                { expand: true, src: ['solution/website/_source/svg_sprite/**.svg'], dest: 'solution/website/_clientv2/images/icons-main/' }
            ]
        }
    },
```

This is my task.